# Why removing CSS snippet is not applied in React component structure?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I have been struggling with some debugging and finding a solution. I have built a page in React. Each conponent is one after another (section under section, one long page)

My App.jsx looks like this:

```
return (
    <>
      <Header handleClickShow={handleClickShow}/>
      <Nav />
      <About />
      <Experience />
      <Portfolio />
      <Contact />
      <Footer />
     {showGame && <Game />}
    </>
  );
```

My indes.js is next:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Some of the components have a section tag ( whatever is inside  )
and that section inside the index.css has margin

```
section {
    margin-top: 8rem;
}
```

So, I have 8rem space after ending each of the components.
My  component is displayed only when I press on the button.
Problem is that when I dont have game displayed I have 8rem extra space under footer. What I dont understand why it dont go away. So when game is not there my component is hidden, but it still leaves the space of 8rem as it is in index.css

I tried to apply new class to a game and take that margin away(I was thibnking issue is there).
When I have game on the page that extra space of 8rem goes under the game component.
I tried to make a div around  in App.jsx but it didnt help.
I know that if I reasign class property closer to component it supposed to apply it, but whatever I do I still have that extra space.
I did try to comment out  component from my App.jsx and when I refresh page still under footer I have that extra 8 rem.

If I comment out section(one showed in code snippet) in index.css then all spaces disappear including the one I have issues, but then whole page is not the way I need.
Maybe someone can give me a hint?
Thank you!

When I inspect page I have next:
[inspect page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOZPF.png)
that is that section tag, but specificly that section with id="inner-shadow-companion" Idk what is that

Is it possible that the external extension that I use in Chrome can cause extra spacing or add an extra element to the page?

Comment: Please inspect elements in browser dev tools and see where from the margin is comming

Comment: I did try that and it shows 0 margin, or I just dont know what to do properly

Comment: Is it possible that the external extension that I use in Chrome can cause an extra spacing or add an extra element to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class with margin 0

```
.no-margin-top {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Then,

```
return (
<>
<Header handleClickShow={handleClickShow}/>
<Nav />
<About />
<Experience />
<Portfolio />
<Contact />
<Footer />
<section className={!showGame ? 'no-margin-top' : ''}>
{showGame && <Game />}
</section>
</>
);
```